# How to move things from many difference folders that have the same file name and rename them based on the folder they come from?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm facing a very complicated process of trying to move almost 100 files from 100 different folders with different folder names. Each folder has the file I want but they share the same file name across all 100 folders. The only thing that distinguishes them is the folder that they are in. I'm working in a terminal Linux command line system using bash so I'd need to code the transfer of these files. I could obviously do it individually but that would take ages.

The reason I want to transfer these files is I want to be able to run an analysis that involves pooling all these files into one folder from the 100 separate folders. However, if I move them they all have the same name which wouldn't work. Is there a way to rename things upon it being moved all in one go instead of individually moving things which would take ages? The key issue is since they all share the same name how do I tell which folder they originate from since that is their identifier.

In terms of what I have tried is I wanted to make a script that would iterate through the folders but the thing is I only need 100/1000 folders there. So I risk getting files from unwanted folders. Given the naming convetion of the folders are as follows

```
  **GSE94671.T_CD5.Sp.ra (Keep)
    GSE94671.T_CD5.Sp.rb (Keep)
    GSE94671.T_CD5.Sp.rc (Keep)
    GSE95337.ETP.Th.ra (Ignore)
    GSE95853.HSPC.BM.rb (Keep)**
```

I couldn't come up with anyway to iteratre through them that avoids the specific folders I don't want.

Comment: you could try appending the folder name to the file name

Comment: There are a few things that linux has have you looked at .sh script or were planning on doing it a different way?

Comment: Iterating over a hundred folders to find files of the form `${FOLDER_NAME}/foo.file` and moving them to a single directory with new name `${FOLDER_NAME}_foo.file` is a simple operation with `bash`.  What have you tried?

Comment: In terms of what I have tried is I wanted to make a script that would iterate through the folders but the thing is I only need 100/1000 folders there. So I risk getting files from unwanted folders. Given the naming convetion of the folders are as follows

  **GSE94671.T_CD5.Sp.ra (Keep)
    GSE94671.T_CD5.Sp.rb (Keep)
    GSE94671.T_CD5.Sp.rc (Keep)
    GSE95337.ETP.Th.ra (Ignore)
    GSE95853.HSPC.BM.rb (Keep)**
I couldn't come up with anyway to iteratre through them that avoids the specific folders I don't want.

Comment: Showing one example of what to keep vs. ignore is not helpful. You need to give a rule to determine one from the other.  How did _you_ make that determination? Translating the rule to bash is the simple part.

Comment: The ones I want I kind of arbitrary based on their names. That's why I'm having difficulty. In the past I've been able to iterate through everything using wildcard place holders and more but with this I'm just lost.

Comment: Please provide a sample input, desired output, what you have so far.  Read [mcve].

Comment: We cannot help if you do not know how to select "good" or "bad" directories, unless you show us the entire list of directories so we can try to find a pattern.